# Flutter : Instgram redirect url not redirecting to the app in ios

Tags: flutter, instagram

I am implementing an Instagram login in my app, I am using [simple_auth_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth_flutter) library for this, Everything is working fine in Android, it takes me to the app and provides me the user's selected Instagram user id, But it is not working in IOS, after select account and permission it takes me to redirect URL but not back to my app, and not getting any data from Instagram,

this issue is in IOS

Here is my code

```
Future<void> _instaGetData() async {
final simpleAuth.InstagramApi _igApi = simpleAuth.InstagramApi(
  "instagram",
  ConstantText.igClientId,
  ConstantText.igClientSecret,
  ConstantText.igRedirectURL,
  scopes: [
    'user_profile', // For getting username, account type, etc.
  ],
);

_igApi.authenticate().then(
  (simpleAuth.Account? _user) async {
    simpleAuth.OAuthAccount user = _user as simpleAuth.OAuthAccount;
    print("USER--> ${user.userData}");
    print("USER--> $_user");

    var igUserResponse =
        await Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: 'https://graph.instagram.com')).get(
      '/me',
      queryParameters: {
        // Get the fields you need.
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user
        "fields": "username, id",
        "access_token": user.token,
      },
    );     
    print("INSTA_RESULT --> ${igUserResponse.data["username"]}");
    setState(() {
      // _userData = igUserResponse.data;
    });
  },
).catchError(
  (Object e) {
    setState(() {
      print("Error--> ${e.toString()}");
    });
  },
);
```

}